# Does position : fixed property in css make that element an inline-block element?

Tags: html, css

```
header{
    display : flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position : fixed;
}
```

after giving the value fixed to position property the header element is taking only required space.
[my html site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ7Pq.jpg)

I expected the header element to take up the full width

Comment: add `width: 100vw` for this.

Answer (score 0):

When defining the position, then you need to set the position either by using:

```
header{
    display: flex;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: fixed;
}
```

or you set the the `width:100%;` or `width:100vw;`,